# R: why does mean not work with a data.frame row but rowMeans does

Tags: r

Just stumbled over a strange beahaviour in R. consider the following code:

```
> x <- data.frame(A=c("A","A"), B1=c(1,2), B2=c(1,2), B3=c(2,1))
> x
  A B1 B2 B3
1 A  1  1  2
2 A  2  2  1

> mean(x[1,-1])
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(x[1, -1]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

> rowMeans(x[,-1])
[1] 1.333333 1.666667
```

Can someone explain why *mean* fails, although all data are numeric?

Comment: `mean(as.numeric(x[1,-1]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the type. `mean` does not work on `list`s:

```r
x <- data.frame(A=c("A","A"), B1=c(1,2), B2=c(1,2), B3=c(2,1))
typeof(x[1,-1])
#R> [1] "list"
class(x[1,-1])
#R> [1] "data.frame"
```

From `?mean`:

> x
> An R object. Currently there are methods for numeric/logical vectors and date, date-time and time interval objects. Complex vectors are allowed for trim = 0, only.

While from `?rowMeans`:

> x
> an array of two or more dimensions, containing numeric, complex, integer or logical values, or a numeric data frame. For .colSums() etc, a numeric, integer or logical matrix (or vector of length m * n).

`x[1,-1]` is a numeric data frame.

Comment: Strangely, adding *as.vector* does not help either, but computing it by hand works: `sum(x[1,]) / length(x[1,]`

Comment: You need to use `unlist`. `is.vector(list())` is `TRUE` so `as.vector` just give you the `list` again.

Comment: Very confusing, but it works. IOW, whenever extracting a row or column from a data.frame, the result must first be "unlisted" before it can be used in claculations?

Comment: It depends on the method. Some might work on `data.frame`s like `rowMeans`. Most, however, will not.